# Python passing read-only char ** as argument to a function

Tags: python-3.x, python-cffi

I have a C library function that expects a `char const **` argument, such as:

```
void set_values(void* object, char const ** values, int dim1, int dim2);
```

Where `values` is an array of `dim1*dim2` length pointing to null terminated string values.

When I try to call this function using cffi/ctypes, the Python code below results in error:

```
LP_c_char  = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)

dim1 = 2
dim2 = 3
values = ('1.0', '2.0', '1.2', '2.2', '1.5', '2.5')

values_ptr = (LP_c_char * (dim1 * dim2))()
for i, value in enumerate(values):
    values_ptr[i] = ctypes.create_string_buffer(value.encode('utf-8'))

mylib.set_values(object, values_ptr, dim1, dim2)
```

The result is the error below at `mylib.set_values(...)` line:

```
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char * *' must be a cdata pointer, not LP_c_char_Array_6
```

Sadly `values` cannot be a `double*` array because the library accepts variable names and expressions.

I was following [this old thread](https://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/704158/). I'm using Python 3.7.2 and cffi 1.14.0.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix ctypes and cffi like that.  They are two different projects.  In this case, you're trying to call a function exposed by cffi but passing arguments that are ctypes objects.  Try building cffi objects instead, e.g. with `ffi.new()`.

Answer (score 0):

Following the accepted answer advice, I found [an example in the cffi documentation](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#an-example-of-calling-a-main-like-thing) that solved the problem. Sharing to whoever else might have the same question.

```
dim1 = 2
dim2 = 3
values = ('1.0', '2.0', '1.2', '2.2', '1.5', '2.5')

values_ptr = [ffi.new("char[]", bytes(value, encoding="utf-8")) for value in values]

mylib.set_values(object, ffi.new("char *[]", values_ptr), dim1, dim2)
```